# Can't access global variable inside function

Tags: php, variables, scope, global-variables

This (simplified version of my code) doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement('<somexml/>');

    function foo(){
        $child = $sxml->addChild('child');
    }

    foo();
?>
```

Why?   I want to access `$sxml` because I want to log errors on it if `foo()` fails.  `foo()` calls itself recursively to create a directory listing, so I fear passing the whole `$sxml` onto itself (as in `foo($sxml)`) could hurt performance.

Is there a way to access `$sxml` inside `$foo` without passing it as an argument? (PHP 5.2.x+)

**EDIT:** What if the code looks like this, actually?

```
<?php
    bar(){
        $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement('<somexml/>');
        function foo(){
            $child = $sxml->addChild('child');
        }
        foo();
    }
    bar();
?>
```

Comment: please, do OOP or just pass it as argument. Reusability is key.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper I understand your point, but I'm just getting started with PHP and this is likely not code that I'll reuse. It's more of a prototype that if goes wrong I can throw away and start from scratch.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You have to pass it to the function:

```
<?php
    $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement('<somexml/>');

    function foo($sxml){
        $child = $sxml->addChild('child');
    }

    foo($sxml);
?>
```

or declare it [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/):

```
<?php
    $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement('<somexml/>');

    function foo(){
        global $sxml;
        $child = $sxml->addChild('child');
    }

    foo();
?>
```

If the variable isn't global but is instead defined in an outer function, the first option (passing as an argument) works just the same:

```
<?php
    function bar() {
        $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement('<somexml/>');
        function foo($sxml) {
            $child = $sxml->addChild('child');
        }
        foo($sxml);
    }
    bar();
?>
```

Alternatively, create a [closure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) by declaring the variable in a `use` clause.

```
<?php
    function bar() {
        $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement('<somexml/>');
        function foo() use(&$xml) {
            $child = $sxml->addChild('child');
        }
        foo();
    }
    bar();
?>
```

Comment: Just one more thing... what if the variable was in a parent function? (question edited) :(

Comment: In your second example you can't access $sxml from foo() because it is locally defined in bar(). A solution could be: declare $sxml outside foo() and bar(), and use it in both functions using global. But as thephpdeveloper suggested, you should use OOP ;)

Answer (score 22):

You need to explicitly invite the global variable into the functions scope:

```
function foo(){
    global $sxml;
    $child = $sxml->addChild('child');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the global keyword to declare $sxml inside your function.

```
<?php
    $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement('<somexml/>');
    function foo(){
    global   $sxml;  
    $child = $sxml->addChild('child');
    }
    foo();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

another solution is to use **$GLOBALS** while you declare that variable:

```
         $my_var   = 'blabla';    // not global
$GLOBALS['my_var'] = 'blabla';    // global  (correct)
```

Answer (score 3):

While the top answer provides a nice solution, I'd like to argue that the appropriate solution in most modern PHP applications is to create a class with a static variable, like so:

```
<?php

class xmlHelper {
    private static $sxml;

    public function getXML() {
        return self::$sxml;
    }

    public function setXML($xml) {
        self::$sxml = $xml;
    }
}

xmlHelper::setXML(new SimpleXMLElement('<somexml/>'));

function foo(){
    $child = xmlHelper::getXML()->addChild('child');
}

foo();
```

This approach allows you to access `$sxml` from within `foo()` just like you wanted, but it has a few advantages over the `global` approach.

1. With this strategy, you will always be able to put a breakpoint inside `setXML()` to find out what part of your application has manipulated this value, which you cannot do when manipulating globals.
2. You avoid polluting the global namespace with a generic variable name `sxml`.