# global variable not available to query constraint in laravel eager load

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, load, closures

I have a global variable that I need to pass to my query:

```
$size = (user input)

$name = (user input)

$items = Items::with('color')->with(['size' => function ($query){

                $query->where('meters', '=', $size);
            }])

                ->where('item_name', '=', $name)
                ->get();
```

The problem with this query is that the $color variable is not available in the closure: I really need to eager load the data instead of joining tables as I already defined a variable that is used in the view.
How can I pass that variable to the closure?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$size = '(size value)';
$items = Items::with('color')
    ->whereHas('size', function ($query) use ($size) {
        $query->where('meters', $size);
    })
    ->where('item_name', $name)
    ->get();
```

Comment: doesn't find he size column, this one doesn't eagerLoad size

Comment: Wait, is 'size' a relationship or a column in Items?

Comment: When using whereHas, I've never needed to also eagerLoad the relationship. What if you do Items::where('color', 'size') ?

Comment: Yes it works as I posted in your reply, it's a relationship because size can be different (cm, inches, mm etc) so the user has a foreign index to size

Answer (score 0):

You just pass it to your function.

```
$items = Items::with('color')->with(['size' => function ($query, $size) {

            $query->where('meters', '=', $size);
        }])

            ->where('item_name', '=', $text)
            ->get();
```

Comment: doesn't work, it throws this error: Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ItemController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}()

Comment: Oh wait sorry I misread the code. where does $color comes or defined?

Comment: don't worry about the color. I made an error writing the code in the question. I updated it. I need to pass $size to the closure

Comment: If the size is already defined then you can just pass it to your function as the first answer. If it's defined somewhere else as global then you should declare it global as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449526/cant-access-global-variable-inside-function

Comment: the problem with this query is that it's returning data also if meters is not equal $size ...